# Rich text editor for django powered social site?

Tags: django, rich-text-editor

Just a thought, can a rich text editor be integrated to a social networking site, so that users can edit the texts font, style etc. Or should every user have a css each? Its just a thought, was just wondering but would be glad if any of you could advice me how to if its possible. Or is there any other way to get those results?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about Django modules to make text boxes into rich text editors? If so, https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/ has a list of examples. Or are you asking if you *should* give users such editing options? That would seem to be a design question rather than just a programming one...

Comment: Yeah, I looked over that wysiwyg packages. But my question is, can the users use that feature, where they can change the font style and colors of the post or say comment? If so, will I need different css for each post or something like that, and how should i do it. Please advice me. Thank you.

Comment: You would not need different css for each post.  All of the wysiwyg editors store the html with inline-css in the database.